# iMac RAM expansion compatibility

Tags: imac, memory

I have an Apple iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017) with 8GB RAM and I would like to expand the memory to 16 GB. I have found the following ram on line (Newegg)and I would like to know if is it compatible and you would recommend it. I live in Bahrain:

Crucial 16GB Kit (8GBx2) DDR4 2400 MT/s (PC4-19200) 260-Pin SODIMM Memory - CT2K8G4SFS824A

Comment: [Data Memory Systems](https://www.datamemorysystems.com/apple-imac-intel-core-i5-quad-core-3-4ghz-27-mne92ll/a-retina-5k-2017-memory-upgrades/) sells RAM for this model, and the specs are: DDR4-2400MHz 260 PIN SODIMM, so Crucial has the right specs, too. _Disclaimer:_ I've trusted Datamem both professionally and personally for RAM for many years. I'm a satisfied consumer, and have no financial or other ties to Datamem.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a support document explaining this, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201191#27inch2017 for your model:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crucial has a compatibility chart here:
https://content.crucial.com/content/dam/crucial/dram-products/mac/flyer/crucial-memory-for-mac-systems-compatibility-chart.pdf

According to their chart, you can install the PC4-2400, or the faster PC4-2666.  I assume it would slow the 2666 to 2400, but get whatever is cheaper.  You could then potentially move the RAM to a newer machine later.

[image: Corsair Mac memory chart]